# Why is sql showing me an error when creating a foreign key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am trying to insert Roomtype `primary key` into Room table as a `foreign key` but shows me with the following error

> Major Error 0x80040E11, Minor Error 0

```
CREATE TABLE Room (
   RoomID nvarchar(8),
   Capacity numeric(3),
   CONSTRAINT FK_TYPE foreign key (Roomtype) references RoomType(Roomtype)
)

Invalid column ID. [ Roomtype ]

CREATE TABLE Room (
    RoomID nvarchar(8) ,
    Capacity numeric(3),
    CONSTRAINT FK_TYPE foreign key (Roomtype) references RoomType(Roomtype)
)

create table RoomType(
    Roomtype nvarchar(2) primary key,
    Description nvarchar(20),
    Responsibility nvarchar(20)
)
```

Comment: Can you please format this question so its readable?

Comment: RoomType does not appear to be in the room table. NOTE: To avoid confusion, don't name tables and fields with the same name.

Comment: I think that you can't have a column with the same name as the table try to change the column ` Roomtype nvarchar(2) primary key` to ` Roomtype_id nvarchar(2) primary key,` and also the referenced columns

Comment: Explain to me how it is not readable

Comment: @Steve hence the foreign key

Comment: `Explain to me how it is not readable`...fps just look at it!

Comment: there is no column Roomtype in Room table

Comment: Thanks... so that means it will still be linked to Roomtype primary right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add roomtype column in Room table.  You are creating foreign key to a non-existent column

```
create table RoomType ( Roomtype nvarchar(2) primary key,

Description nvarchar(20), Responsibility nvarchar(20)

)

CREATE TABLE Room ( RoomID nvarchar(8) , Capacity numeric(3),Roomtype nvarchar(2),

CONSTRAINT FK_TYPE foreign key (Roomtype) references RoomType(Roomtype)

)
```

Comment: Will that link the table RoomType in result?